# Retrieving Solidity Event Data with Ethers.js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I'm new to Solidity and Ethers.js, so if there are any amateurish mistakes, that would be why.

I'm trying to build a dApp that runs a function on my smart contract, retrieves the data that is emitted from the event, and then displays it on my front-end. I've gotten it to run on Localhost so far. Currently, MetaMask connects to my front-end, but it throws an error when I try to confirm a transaction with the contract.

Create Function (JS):

```
    async function create() {
        ///Acquiring values
        postBody = document.getElementById("in-1-pbd").value;
        postSubcat = document.getElementById("in-2-sc").value;
        console.log(postBody + ", " + postSubcat);
        ///Connecting with Ethereum
        await requestAccount()
        if (typeof window.ethereum != 'undefined') {
          const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
          const signer = provider.getSigner();
          const contract = new ethers.Contract(blokracyAddress, Blokracy.abi, signer)
          const transaction = await contract.createBallot(postSubcat, postBody)
          await transaction.wait()
        ///Building and presenting the ballot
        contract.on("Creation", (message, idnum ) => {
          console.log("Creation Event Data: ", message, idnum);
          buildBallot(Wallet.publicKey, idnum, postBody);
          });
        } else {
          window.alert("Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider installing MetaMask.")
        }
      }
```

Request Account Function:

```
      async function requestAccount() {
        await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      }
```

Create Function (Solidity):

```
///Event Declaration
    event Creation(string message, uint idnum);
///Functionality
///Creating a Ballot:
    function createBallot(
        string memory _subcategory, string memory _post
    ) public {

        ///Set Operator
        operator = msg.sender;

        ///Increment ballotNum
        ballotNum ++;

        ///Apply specifics to ballot
        ballot[ballotNum] = Ballot(
            ballotNum, _subcategory, operator,
            _post, 0, 0, 0, 0
        );

        ///return string and ballotNum
        emit Creation("Ballot was successfully posted!", ballotNum);
        
    }
```

Any insight would be amazing. Like I said, I'm new and trying to learn as much as I can about dApps by building this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach for calling function of smart contract in front-end with the help of web3.

```
const web3 = new Web3(sNetworkRPCURL);
const oDefaultWeb3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
let oContractObject;
let sWalletAddress;

async function metamaskConnection(){
    const aReqAccount = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });
    sWalletAddress=aReqAccount[0];

}
async function create() {
        ///Acquiring values
        postBody = document.getElementById("in-1-pbd").value;
        postSubcat = document.getElementById("in-2-sc").value;
        console.log(postBody + ", " + postSubcat);
        ///Connecting with Ethereum

        if(typeof window.ethereum=="undefined"){
            console.log("METAMASK IS NOT FOUND");
            return;
        }

        oContractObject = new web3.eth.Contract(aContractABI,sContractAddress);
        let oNewContractObject = new oDefaultWeb3.eth.Contract(aContractABI,sContractAddress);

       
        let estimatedGas;      
    
        try {
            estimatedGas = await oNewContractObject.methods
                .createBallot(postSubcat, postBody)
                .estimateGas({
                    from: sWalletAddress                    
                });
    
            console.log("Estimated Gas: ", estimatedGas);
        } catch (error){          
    
            console.log(error);   
    
            return;
        }
        try {
            await oNewContractObject.methods
                .createBallot(postSubcat, postBody)
                .send({
                    from: sWalletAddress,                   
                    gas: estimatedGas,
                })
                .on("transactionHash", (txHash) => {
                    console.log("Transaction Hash: ", txHash);                    
                })
                .on("receipt", async (txReceipt) => {
                    console.log("Receipt: ", txReceipt);   
                   
                })
                .catch("error", (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
           
        }
    }
```

And I want just clarification on web3 object and oDefaultWeb3 objects which I have taken in my code. fist web3 object I will use it for view or call() methods. And other one is useful for send() methods.

So, Now I hope this approach will helpful for you to developing dApps and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You can get events like this:

```
const from = "some address"
const filter = uni.filters.Transfer(from)

const logs = await uni.queryFilter(filterFromAddress1orAddress2)
```

If you want all the parameters, including the non-indexed, you need to create an interface and parse the logs:

```
const interface = new ethers.Interface(ABI)

const parsedLogs = logs.map(log => {
    return interface.parseLog({ data: log.data, topics: log.topics });
})
```